# I am setting up a Java Minecraft server, 1.19.2 forge with a small modlist — I keep getting this error

Tags: java, minecraft

I am setting up a Java Minecraft server, 1.19.2 forge with a small modlist — I keep getting this error.

This is the log

```
[25Mar2023 11:10:11.541] [main/INFO] [cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--launchTarget, forgeserver, --fml.forgeVersion, 43.2.8, --fml.mcVersion, 1.19.2, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, --fml.mcpVersion, 20220805.130853]
[25Mar2023 11:10:11.550] [main/INFO] [cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 10.0.8+10.0.8+main.0ef7e830 starting: java version 20 by Oracle Corporation; OS Windows 10 arch amd64 version 10.0
[25Mar2023 11:10:12.535] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: SpongePowered MIXIN Subsystem Version=0.8.5 Source=union:/C:/Users/heavy/OneDrive/Desktop/minecraft%20server/libraries/org/spongepowered/mixin/0.8.5/mixin-0.8.5.jar%2363!/ Service=ModLauncher Env=SERVER
[25Mar2023 11:10:13.258] [main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\heavy\OneDrive\Desktop\minecraft server\libraries\net\minecraftforge\fmlcore\1.19.2-43.2.8\fmlcore-1.19.2-43.2.8.jar is missing mods.toml file
[25Mar2023 11:10:13.265] [main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\heavy\OneDrive\Desktop\minecraft server\libraries\net\minecraftforge\javafmllanguage\1.19.2-43.2.8\javafmllanguage-1.19.2-43.2.8.jar is missing mods.toml file
[25Mar2023 11:10:13.270] [main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\heavy\OneDrive\Desktop\minecraft server\libraries\net\minecraftforge\lowcodelanguage\1.19.2-43.2.8\lowcodelanguage-1.19.2-43.2.8.jar is missing mods.toml file
[25Mar2023 11:10:13.275] [main/WARN] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser/LOADING]: Mod file C:\Users\heavy\OneDrive\Desktop\minecraft server\libraries\net\minecraftforge\mclanguage\1.19.2-43.2.8\mclanguage-1.19.2-43.2.8.jar is missing mods.toml file
[25Mar2023 11:10:13.440] [main/INFO] [net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.JarInJarDependencyLocator/]: Found 2 dependencies adding them to mods collection
[25Mar2023 11:10:16.212] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: Compatibility level set to JAVA_17
[25Mar2023 11:10:16.477] [main/INFO] [mixin/]: Successfully loaded Mixin Connector [shetiphian.core.mixins.MixinConnector]
[25Mar2023 11:10:16.477] [main/INFO] [cpw.mods.modlauncher.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Launching target 'forgeserver' with arguments []
[25Mar2023 11:10:16.633] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Reference map 'immersive_paintings-common-refmap.json' for immersive_paintings.mixin.json could not be read. If this is a development environment you can ignore this message
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.240] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: de/maxhenkel/gravestone/events/DeathEvents (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.maxhenkel.gravestone.events.DeathEvents)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.240] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: de/maxhenkel/corpse/events/DeathEvents (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.maxhenkel.corpse.events.DeathEvents)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.304] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: net/minecraft/world/item/ItemStack (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.323] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: @Mixin target net.minecraft.world.item.ItemStack was not found tombstone.mixins.json:ItemStackMixin
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.439] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.439] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.439] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.439] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.455] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.455] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.465] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.465] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.465] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.465] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.479] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.479] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.495] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.495] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.502] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/Map$Entry (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
[25Mar2023 11:10:17.547] [main/WARN] [mixin/]: Error loading class: java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64)
```

I've tried updating Java, made sure I've got Java 8 and whatnot, I'm really at a loss.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server) v1.17+ require java 17+, so 8 is too old

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: How are you launching the server jar?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you may need a newer version of Java to run a Minecraft server.

For example, you can download Java 17 on [Oracle's Site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/), or from [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) (open source).

---

*If you are interested, see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52431765/18505766) about differences in Java OpenJDK implementations*

---

EDIT: Reading the log you posted, it seems like you are running Java 20. You could try a lower version.